# Transaction history of accounts for a contract

Tags: solidity

I want to get the transaction history of the transactions that have been performed by the accounts using my contract (on a private blockchain).

If I perform transactions using the `eth.sendTransaction(tx_object)` i.e., without using any contract. Then I am able to get the details of the trasaction using `eth.getTransactionReceipt(tx_hash)`.

`eth.getTransactionReceipt(tx_hash)` returns a transaction object which has a `from` field and a `to` field, where each of these has the desired value of the account addresses which were involved in the transaction.

The problem arises when I use a custom contract. I created a contract, which is as follows:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract MyBank{

    mapping (address => uint) public balance;

    address bankManager;

    event Transfer(address _from, address _to, uint _value);

    function MyBank() {
        bankManager = msg.sender;
        balance[msg.sender] = 10000;
    }

    function transfer(address _to, uint _value) {
        if (balance[msg.sender] >= _value) {
            balance[msg.sender] -= _value;
            balance[_to] += _value;
        }
        Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
    }
}
```

I execute the `transfer()` method which gets executed successfully and the transfer happens. Now when I call the `eth.getTransactionReceipt(tx_hash)`  for this transaction, it returns me a transaction object, which has content of `from` and `to` field as follows:

`from` field contains the address of the account who initiated the transaction,

`to` field contains the contract address.

So the question is, how can I get or build the transaction history for a particular account if I am triggering transaction from my own custom contract.

Comment: In case if the question is not explanatory enough or is unclear, you can ask it here in comments.